# G Apps Script "We're sorry, a server error occurred." when installing a trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-workspace

I'm attempting to install an `onFormSubmit` trigger to a Google Sheet. When running the `setTrigger` function below, I receive this error:

```
Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
setTrigger  @ Code.gs:6
```

What I've tried:

- Waiting a bit and trying again.
- Disabling the V8 runtime for the project.
- Removing all other code and code files except what is absolutely necessary.
- Trying `openById`, `openByUrl`, `getActive`, and `getActiveSpreadsheet` to open the spreadsheet.
- Logging out of all other Chrome profiles on my device.
- Restarting my device.
- Clearing my browser cache.
- Starting over in a new project (with a Form and linked Sheet).
- Adding the trigger from the menu Triggers > Add Trigger.
- In one last move of desperation, asking ChatGPT (it had no idea).

Oddly, trying to add the trigger from the Triggers > Add Trigger menu also fails. The error says "Something went wrong. Please reload the page to try again," and gives the option to dismiss or reload. Reloading does not fix the issue. Other triggers also fail (I have tried "On open").

I have reproduced the error in a new project using this code, contained by the linked Spreadsheet.

```js
function setTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmail")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

function sendEmail(e)
{
  // No code necessary to reproduce the error.
}
```

I want this to work from code, but I think it will also work for me if it is added from the Triggers > Add Trigger menu. Thank you in advance for your help!

Edit: This seems specific to Google Workspace. My regular gmail.com account works as expected.

Comment: You may be concerned by a bug reported here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/282113264 feel free to click +1 to add more weight.

Comment: These do seem related! Thanks for sharing.